# How to create an anchor tag of General Link field

Tags: sxa, content-search

We are getting results through `Content Search API` and getting the `General Link field` value into it. We would like to add an `anchor link` based on a `general link field` value. Do we have the default feature of `Sitecore` to create an `anchor link` in view or do we need to use custom code to create a link?

Answer (score 2):

To update the General Link field named GeneralLinkField in the `/Sitecore/Content/Home` item in the Master database to the anchor `namedAnchor`:

```
Sitecore.Data.Database master = Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetDatabase("master");
Sitecore.Data.Items.Item home = master.GetItem("/sitecore/content/home");
Sitecore.Data.Fields.LinkField linkField = home.Fields["generallinkfield"];
home.Editing.BeginEdit();
linkField.Clear();
linkField.LinkType = "anchor";
linkField.Url = "namedAnchor";
home.Editing.EndEdit();
```

You can also check the link type and perform the functionality as required:

```
 switch (generalLinkfield.LinkType.ToLower())
    {
      case "internal":        
        return generalLinkfield.TargetItem != null ? Sitecore.Links.LinkManager.GetItemUrl(generalLinkfield.TargetItem) : string.Empty;
      case "media":      
        return generalLinkfield.TargetItem != null ? Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaManager.GetMediaUrl(generalLinkfield.TargetItem) : string.Empty;
      case "external":      
        return generalLinkfield.Url;
      case "anchor":
        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(generalLinkfield.Anchor) ? "#" + generalLinkfield.Anchor : string.Empty;
      case "mailto":
        return generalLinkfield.Url;
      case "javascript":
        return generalLinkfield.Url;
      default:
        return generalLinkfield.Url;
    }
```

for more details please refer [Access general link fields](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/102/sitecore-experience-manager/access-general-link-fields.html)